# Why does the bracha-maker eat a piece of challah first?

Tags: blessing, challah-shabbat-bread

I'm wondering if anyone knows the origins of why the one who makes the bracha on challah on Shabbat takes a piece for himself first. I'm most curious if this actually shows up in sources, or if it's a custom (or both, obviously). Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Efrayim and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I'm a bit perplexed why you'd think to ask this. Why wouldn't he take for himself first? He's hungry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed the correct practice. Whenever one person is saying the blessing for everyone present at a more formal meal, and is providing each of them with a piece from his loaf, they should not eat before he does.

(Note that according to some opinions there is no problem if he passes them their pieces before he eats, but they should not start eating before he does.
According to others he should not even pass them their pieces before he eats.)

See [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 167:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.167.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) with Mishnah Berurah, [particularly 79](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.167.79?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: I always thought that after having said the blessing one should perform the act without interruption, yet Rema's comment seems to contradict this. Is there a word on this issue?

Comment: @Kazibácsi see the Mishnah Berurah there 78 and 79